# c# create a new form with a button click and add control to the new created form

Tags: c#

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        Form myForm = new Form();
        myForm.Show();
    }

    public void createControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox Text = new TextBox();
        Text.Text = "Hi Hello";
        Text.ForeColor = Color.BlueViolet;
        Text.BackColor = Color.Silver;
        Text.Top = top;
        Text.Left = 20;
        using (var myForm = new Form())
        {
            myForm.Controls.Add(Text); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But.... which is the question?

Comment: The form you are showing in `button2_Click()` is a different one from the one created in `createControl_Click()`. You are not showing the form with a `TextBox` added to it.

Comment: OOP:You can have many instances of a class; in fact you create a new instance with every call of `new`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As they mentioned in the comments, you created 2 different objects from Form class.
You add textbox to one of them but display the other one.

You can solve this by creating a member for form1 class with type of Form and work with that in every method. Something like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Form _myForm;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _myForm = new Form();
    }

    public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        _myForm.Show();
    }

    public void createControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox Text = new TextBox();
        Text.Text = "Hi Hello";
        Text.ForeColor = Color.BlueViolet;
        Text.BackColor = Color.Silver;
        Text.Top = top;
        Text.Left = 20;

        _myForm.Controls.Add(Text);
        
    }
}
```